# What is the common knowledge about NPOI, EPPlus and Koogra as of 2015?

Tags: excel, epplus, npoi

Yes, Koogra only reads. EPPlus only supports .xlsx and is buggy in edge cases.

- What else should one know for choosing between them?
- Is one of them much slower than others?
- NPOI seems way to complicated and is a Java port, so is it worth
  using?
- Should one use EPPlus for .xlsx and NPOI for .xls?
- What is the general knowledge about them today?

Answer (score 14):

1. `Jet/ACE OLE DB` either read worksheet as strings, or as typed columns, so you either lose numbers precision or you must have headers in the first row. Thus, they are to be avoided.
2. No library supports XLS**B**.
3. Speed.

   - For a large XLS, the time of reading for `NPOI`:`Jet`:`Koogra`:`EDR` is 14:8:7:5.
   - For the same XLS**X**, the time for `EPPlus`:`NPOI`:`Koogra`:`EDR` is 52:36:20:16.
   - For relatively small files with many tabs `EPPlus` can be a bit faster than `EDR`.
4. Errors (#DIV/0!, #VALUE!) etc.

   - `EDR` and `Koogra` don't explicitly support errors. `EDR` reads them as usual strings, `Koogra` -- as blank cells.
   - `NPOI` and `EPPlus` do.
5. Koogra reads dates as [OLE date] numbers and they are undistinguishable from real numbers. Also it sometimes reads numbers with many decimals digits incorrectly. `EDR` gets this fine. So, no to `Koogra`.
6. `NPOI` is complicated, 5 dlls of 4 MB. `Koogra` and `EDR` are simple, 200 KB and two dlls (themselves and zip) each.
7. `EDR` works as a `IDataReader`, so it reads data sequentially. It also has built-in function to get a `DataSet`. With sequential read yoou can only go through first sheet in the work book. `Koogra` supports random access to cells and sheets.
8. `EDR` is based on `SharpZip`, `Koogra` is based on `Ionic.Zip`. The former allows to open a file from .zip a `Stream` which can be benefical for other parts of the project.

I haven't looked at writing aspects of `NPOI`, so without the need to distinguish errors, I would go with `EPPlus` for .xlsx and with EDR for reading .xls.

Comment: Why EPPlus for .xlsx if EDR is reading faster, as you said in 3.?

Comment: @titol Well, because I already had it tested, and also because EDR is faster for very-very large files, about 100 megabytes. For smaller files around 2 megabytes, EPPlus is faster. And it just works, you don't have to wrap EDR's DataSet into own Excel-like data model.